# Remove duplicates from DataFrame based on two columns, while considering permutations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
+------------------+--------------------+
| Player's Country | Opponent's Country |
+------------------+--------------------+
|       U.K.       |       France       |
+------------------+--------------------+
|      France      |        U.K.        |
+------------------+--------------------+
|       Japan      |        Spain       |
+------------------+--------------------+
|       Spain      |        Japan       |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

and I want to remove duplicates based on both columns and on their permutation. Meaning, that I would like to keep only the first of the two rows with the U.K. and France as the two players' countries, and only the first of the two rows with Japan and Spain.

I know there is `df.drop_duplicates(subset=[col1, col2], keep='first')` but that does not consider permutations. How can I do this in an efficient way?

Comment: whats your ideal output ? `df.stack().drop_duplicates().unstack()` should do the trick